# Hiro Macro - Toast notification not appearing

Tags: android, automation, macros

I have been using the Android app Hiro Macro for automation and am fairly used to it, but I am completely stumped on variables. I just need to know how to create a random number and then paste it to where the Android cursor is.

I copied the example script from [here](http://prohiro.com/?page_id=399#rand), played it, and nothing happened. I expect to see a toast notification with a random number. This is the exact script I'm using:

```
var #count 0

:start

// 20 or less 10 or more (#count)

rand #count 10 20 

// shows toast message.

toast Random is #count

// Wait 2 second (1000 = 1 sec.) 

sleep 2000

// Restart. Infinite loop.

goto :start
:end
```

Comment: Post the exact code you have tried. We can't solve it for you unless you show us what you've done.

Comment: Code is above but I cant format it properly. Its exactly as the example script that the link goes to.....And I can't even get this running properly, which leads me to believe I am missing something glaringly obvious but I cant work it out

Comment: What do you mean you can't format it properly? Just select it all and click the `{}` button.

Comment: K its done now, sorry , just not familiar with the site

Comment: How do you know your script is running? I just installed the app and tested it and it worked fine for me. Try changing the action button (in settings) from volume down to a button on the screen.

Comment: When you play it will vibrate , then vibrate again at the end...Yeah I already have mine set to a screen button anyway..Did you use that exact example script though? And you got the toast ?

Comment: Yep, I just checked, my script is _exactly_ the same and works fine (I see `Random is 18`, `Random is 13`, etc.). What phone and version of Android do you have?

Comment: Did you check if there's something in the log after running the script? The second button from the right in Hiro will show the log. Also when you start the script do you see a toast that says `Play start!`? If you don't see that then it's not something wrong with your script, it's something with your phone or with Hiro generally.

Comment: Omg, I cant believe what I've done it's just dawned on me.. I got an app ages ago called Notifications Off because of persistent annoying notifications from tons of apps.....And HiroMacro was blocked by it  XD  I am so special . Thanks for your time though :)

Comment: Haha no worries, I've copied a lot of the information I wrote into an answer. You should accept that if it was my suggestion to check for the `Play start!` toast that solved it for you. Even if I didn't solve it for you, hopefully my answer can help someone in future :)

Comment: Sure , but how do I "accept" answer?

Comment: Oh and also, how would I "type" the number into a running macro ? Say if its a text doc? Normally I just fast type keys , but obv this is different

Comment: To accept an answer, click the checkmark to the left of it so that it lights up green. Regarding typing numbers into a running macro, sorry, I don't know. I've never used Hiro, I only installed it to see if your script would work. I would suggest googling, or asking another question. Only this time I might suggest asking on the [Android Stack Exchange](https://android.stackexchange.com/) site (in case you're not aware, Stack Overflow is only one of many, _many_ Stack Exchange sites).

Comment: Ok , thanks a lot for your time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some things to check:

- How do you know your script is running? I just installed the app and tested it and it worked fine for me. Try changing the action button (in settings) from volume down to a button on the screen.
- Check if there's something in the log after running the script. The second button from the right in Hiro will show the log.
- When you start the script do you see a toast that says `Play start!`? If you don't see that then it's not something wrong with your script, it's something with your phone or with Hiro generally.